# redirect url to another url using htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an url `http://example.com/xyz/`, and i want this url as `http://example.com/xyz`
xyz is only for example it could be anything. Please help me. your help would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove trailing slash you can use this rule as your first rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: have another url `http://example.com/xyz/abx/` in this url i also want to remove trailing slash. would you please help me?

Comment: This rule would remove trailing slash from that as well as long as `/xyz/abx/` is not a directory.

Comment: Hope `/blog/abc/` is not a directory. Does `/blog/` also have .htaccess? If yes then this rule need to be added there also.

Comment: i added this rule there but url is redirected to `http://example.com/abc` not to `http://example.com/blog/abc`

Comment: Oh for that just change `/$1` to `$1` in last rule.